# NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have this problem:

> [RecipesViewController setRecipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a0a9f0
>   2011-08-31 13:57:33.328 Recipes[8137:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RecipesViewController setRecipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a0a9f0'

This is my ViewController:

and this is my Recipe class:

Thanks in advance for help..

Comment: Check IBOutlet for **RecipesViewController** and also the method **setRecipe** is not properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is not setRecipe method defined in your RecipesViewController.  Ensure that spelling and casing are correct in your class.